# How to redirect Selenium tests to remote machine using Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I ran WebDriver tests using Maven from Jenkins on Linux. My selenium automated tests failed because the browser was not being opened. I'm thinking of redirecting my tests and run them on remote machine (Windows). How can it be done? If you have better ideas, please speak up.

Comment: do you use WebDriver or Selenium 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my point of view [Selenium 2 Grid](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) is the way to go

You can start the Grid via batch files, JSON, or ant...

Comment: Hey Frank, I just added my comment below regarding the Grid. I'm not quite clear how it could be done in my enviroment.

Comment: I researched some more and found out that Grid might work for me. So 
installed Selenium Grid plug in on Jenkins machine and now it is running as hub and I started the node on a Windows machine. I registered it and I see the hub and the node are seeing each other. But when I kick a Jenkins job which runs my tests, I get the error message that Firefox is not installed on Linux machine. It makes me think that the tests are run on the hub instead of the node. Do you have any suggestion what i might be missing? Thanks!

Comment: I was using FirefoxDriver but I guess I need to switch to RemoteWebDriver. What i got from more reseaching is i need to add the following lines inside each test: DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability); I'm try that and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, I see the hub instance and the node under(localhost:4444/grid/console) Grid Hub 2.15.0
DefaultRemoteProxylistening on http://1.1.1.:58018 (hub)
test session time out after 300 sec.

DefaultRemoteProxylistening on http://3.3.3.3:5555 (node)
test session time out after 300 sec.
Supports up to 5 concurrent tests from: 

Should I see both instances (hub and node) on the page?

Comment: Thanks! So far i've got one test where i added RemoteWebDriver where I specify but it still tries to run on the hub (and fails) and doesn't want to run on the node machine. Any suggestions here?

Comment: Frank, does it look right to you?                              public void myTest(Platform WINDOWS) throws Exception {
       
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://hub.jenkins.home:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());                        
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capability.setBrowserName("firefox"); 
        capability.setPlatform(WINDOWS);
        capability.setVersion("15.0");   
    }                                                                     Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's helpful but we do use Junit in house. We do build tests for the client using selenium and for the server we use something else that run on junit. I don't have programming experience and I basically just copied what others do and try to understand why it's done that way. Finally i solved the problem that I had with selenium test running on a remote machine. As usual it turned out to be a really small issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mentioned above "you don't have to add the RemoteWebDriver creation for each test... it's better to reduce that because it's very time consuming". Could you suggest a better way?

Comment: you can for instance do it once in a class... without programming experience I won't recommend any further ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium Grid where you have to create hub,hub is where your server is started and then create node, node is where you are going to run your tests. You can learn it from [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.html).

Comment: I don't think Grid will work because I'm not manually trigger the selenium server from the command line. Everything is configured through Jenkins. I build, deploy builds and run the tests on the same machine. However if the hub and node can be started by jenkins after the build deployed, i could considered the option. Can you let me how it's done?